# How should I do a navigation screen in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, uinavigationcontroller, conventions

I want to build a navigation screen, just like installation shields has (next/previous stuff), maybe a bit more sophisticated.. How is this usually done in WinForms?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for a Wizard design.

I've successfully used this one:

[Wizard Form Implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/WizardForm.aspx)

CodeProject has many more.  Try searching there.

Comment: from a quick glance this doesn't support anything like jumping to a specific screen, etc. (programmly)

Comment: Look at the sample, specifically the WizardPage1 class.  In it the next page is programmatically determined by the user's selection on the previous step.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a wizard, and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ak_wizard.aspx) is a detailed article.